# How to print specific values from deeply nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have the following nested dictionary variable `dict2` and I need to print only the value in `VarCharValue` (I am using python 2.7)

I tried using

```
print (" {0[ResultSet][Rows]}".format(dict2))
```

but not able to get the values inside Data

```
print dict2

{u'ResultSet': {u'Rows': [{u'Data': [{u'VarCharValue': u'CNT'}]}, {u'Data': [{u'VarCharValue': u'1'}]}], u'ResultSetMetadata': {u'ColumnInfo': [{u'Scale': 0, u'Nullable': u'UNKNOWN', u'TableName': u'', u'Precision': 19, u'CatalogName': u'hive'}]}}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200,'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Fr GMT', 'connection': 'keep-alive'}}}
```

***Required output***

```
CNT
1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a lot subdicts (but also lists) inside your dictionary, so you need to index all of them until you get to the desired elements:

```
print ("{0[ResultSet][Rows][0][Data][0][VarCharValue]}".format(dict2)) 
print ("{0[ResultSet][Rows][1][Data][0][VarCharValue]}".format(dict2))
```

which prints:

```
CNT
1
```

Comment: Amazing. I never knew format supported this kind of operation.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive function will do the job. It may be far from being fast but still would be suitable for most cases. You may feed a dictionary of whatever structure to it, pass a the name of the key you want and voila.

```
    dict2 = {u'ResultSet': {u'Rows': [{u'Data': [{u'VarCharValue': u'CNT'}]}, {u'Data': [{u'VarCharValue': u'1'}]}], u'ResultSetMetadata': {u'ColumnInfo': [{u'Scale': 0, u'Nullable': u'UNKNOWN', u'TableName': u'', u'Precision': 19, u'CatalogName': u'hive'}]}}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200,'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Fr GMT', 'connection': 'keep-alive'}}}

    def get_dict_values(from_dict, get_key):
        '''
        Return the values of specified keys from a nested dictionary.
        '''

        # A list to collect resulting values in.
        list_collect = list()

        # For each key in a dict.
        for dict_key in from_dict.keys():
            # If it's value is an instance of dict.
            if isinstance(from_dict[dict_key], dict):
                # Call self recursively.
                get_list = get_dict_values(from_dict[dict_key], get_key)

                # Extend the list_collect with what we've got from recursive call.
                list_collect.extend(get_list)
            # If a value is anything iterable.
            elif isinstance(from_dict[dict_key], (list, set, tuple, frozenset)):
                # Call self for each element.
                for list_elem in from_dict[dict_key]:
                    # Extend the list_collect with what we've got from recursive call.
                    get_list = get_dict_values(list_elem, get_key)
                    list_collect.extend(get_list)
            elif dict_key == get_key:
                list_collect.extend([from_dict[dict_key]])
        return list_collect

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        varchar_values = get_dict_values(dict2, 'VarCharValue')
        print(varchar_values)
```

It will return a list e.g. `['CNT', '1']` so if you want your values as strings just do something like `'\n'.join(varchar_values)`.

Comment: Thanks for your input.